# How do I interpret the results of my ANOVA f-test?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, anova

I have a fairly simple question, I am struggling with how to interpret my f-test results and what they mean about  the variables, Insta and Twitter.

Model 1:

```
log(Salary) ~ Twitter + Insta + PPG + RPG + MPPG
```

Model 2:

```
log(Salary) ~ PPG + RPG + MPPG
```

My main question is do Insta and Twitter have a significant effect on salary based off these figures?

```
lm4 <- lm(log(Salary) ~ Twitter + Insta + PPG + RPG + MPPG, data = Econ_III_Data_Set1[423:618,])    
lm5 <- lm(log(Salary) ~ PPG + RPG + MPPG, data = Econ_III_Data_Set1[423:618,])   
anova(lm4 , lm5)
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq    F   Pr(>F)
1    190 94.450                           
2    192 94.856 -2    -0.406 0.4084 0.6653
```

Comment: Is 0.6653 your p-value? It would help if you posted the R commands you used.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the p-value for the difference between models `lm4` and `lm5` is 0.6653. That p-value means that even if `lm4` and `lm5` were not different (the null hypothesis), if you repeated this data sampling and analysis multiple times you would find this large a difference between the models in about 66% of trials (provided that the assumptions required for analysis of variance hold). The usual standard for a "statistically significant" difference requires less than a 5% chance of finding a difference just by chance if the models aren't different. So you can fairly safely say that model `lm4` does not significantly improve upon model `lm5`.

Comment: @NC86 No need to thank EdM for his answer. Since you are new to CV, the usually practice is to accept the answer and upvote it if it helped you with your question and solved your problem.